# Google App ID losing after upgrading NWJS to last version from 0.37.3

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, nwjs

I have a legacy Google Chrome installable Apps packaged with NWJS as a standalone app.

I were using NWJS version 0.37.3 but now had to upgrade to last 0.56.0 because of Big Sur compatibility problems.

Now the problem is that the app generated with last NWJS sdk don't mantain old Google chrome app ID but got a new ID (testable in console with ***chrome.runtime.id***).

So upgrading installed apps I were loosing old local data (local files, database, settings etc).

In manifest.json I have a "key" field with the app key that in old 0.37.3 was responsible to maintain chrome.runtime.id.

How I can keep using the same chrome.runtime.id with new NWJS SDK or any workaround to not loose existing local data?

My current manifest.json

```
{
    "key": "MIGfM....B",
    "name": "MyApp",
    "description": "my app",
    "version": "309",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "default_locale": "en",
    "nodejs": true,
    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>",
        "storage",
        "browser",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        {
            "fileSystem": ["write", "retainEntries", "directory"]
        },
        "videoCapture",
        "nativeMessaging",
        "webview"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/favicon/favicon-16x16.png",
        "128": "images/favicon/apple-icon-128x128.png"
    },
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": [
                ...
            ]
        }
    },
    "chromium-args": "--ignore-certificate-errors",
    "build": {
        "appId": "my.app",
        "nwFlavor": "sdk",
        "output": "../package/",
        "nwVersion": "0.56.0",
        "outputPattern": "${NAME}-${VERSION}-${PLATFORM}-${ARCH}",
        "targets": ["zip"],
        "win": {
            "icon": "images/favicon/win-app.ico",
            "copyright": "..."
        },
        "mac": {
            "icon": "images/favicon/mac/icon.icns",
            "copyright": "..."
        },
        "nsis": {
            "icon": "images/favicon/win-app.ico"
        },
        "excludes": ["**/bower_components", "**/bower_components/**/*"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this, but seems like something that should be documented. I've created an open spreadsheet (anyone with link can edit), that documents all the versions of NW.js and their details. The data comes from [the official versions list](https://nwjs.io/versions.json). And I've manually added the `chrome.runtime.id`'s for some versions I had locally. I think some scripting will be needed to flesh out the rest of the versions, but at least there is now a public place for the info to go to.

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16Y-mH5GzFL8BXLXCwzkvKQ7Vg4t4c2Jt6WgZaAAZPwc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: what key are using in the manifest.json for the tests? Because [in theory](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/key/) the is the key attribute that control the result.

Comment: There is no manifest. I'm literally just opening NW.js and typing `chrome.runtime.id` into the console. or on the non-sdks doing a [2-line package.json](https://dev.to/thejaredwilcurt/holy-shit-nw-js-is-so-easy-1h6) and an HTML file to insert the result of `chrome.runtime.id` into the DOM for copy/paste.